# Can i sum two String values without using Wrapper Class in java if yes than how ?

Tags: java

```
String result = "";
try{
 int value = Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b);
 result = ""+value;
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
 //either a or b is not a number
 result = "Invalid input";
}
MyStringSum.show(null,a+b);
```

I am using Wrapper Class but i want to sum two String values without using
Wrapper Class , can i do this?

Comment: Yes you can, but if it's not an exercise, there's no reason to not use `parseInt`.

Comment: Well you're using a static method within `Integer`, but you're not creating any *instances* of `Integer`, if that's what you were worried about. If you want to do it without using `parseInt`, basically you'd have to reimplement `parseInt` yourself. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Actually this question asked by Interviewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry about the efficiency of your implementation, because it is not using any wrapper objects.

`java.lang.Integer` plays several roles:

1. It holds several important constants, such as `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE`,
2. It serves as a helper class for working with primitive `int`s by providing *class methods* for parsing and manipulating them, and
3. Its instances serve as `Object` wrappers for primitive `int`s, and providing *instance methods* for it.

Because you use only `parse(...)`, which is a *class method*, your code uses the class in its capacity #2, ignoring the #1 and #3. In other words, you are not using `Integer` in its "wrapper for `int`" capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/)**. Example(from the link):

```
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
        .variables("x", "y")
        .build()
        .setVariable("x", 2.3)
        .setVariable("y", 3.14);
double result = e.evaluate();
```

Another option is **[Javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/)**. See the link for example.

And there's **[EvalX](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx)**. See below example(from the link):

```
Expression expression = new Expression("1+1/3");
result = expression.eval():
expression.setPrecision(2);
result = expression.eval():
```

I hope this helps!